# Query data.table by key in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have followed the data.table introduction. A key is set on the x column of the data.table and then queried. I have tried to set the key on the v column and it does not work has expected. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

```
> set.seed(34)
> DT = data.table(x=c("b","b","b","a","a"),v=rnorm(5))
> DT
   x          v
1: b -0.1388900
2: b  1.1998129
3: b -0.7477224
4: a -0.5752482
5: a -0.2635815
> setkey(DT,v)
> DT[1.1998129,]
   x          v
1: b -0.7477224  

EXPECTED:
   x          v
1: b  1.1998129
```

Comment: @poiuytrez I guess it is FAQ7.29. `DT[5,v]-1.1998129#[1] -3.393616e-09
 `.  You may not get the same problem if you convert that column `v` to `character and then do `setkey(..)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg The strange thing about `DT[J()]` is due to floating error. If you try `DT[J(DT$v[5])]` you have the correct result.

Comment: @akrun Where is the FAQ 7.29?

Comment: @poiuytrez Actually, it is FAQ7.31 `http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first argument of `[.data.table` is a number, it will not do a join, but a simple row number lookup. Since after the `setkey` your `data.table` looks like so:

```
DT
#   x          v
#1: b -0.7477224
#2: a -0.5752482
#3: a -0.2635815
#4: b -0.1388900
#5: b  1.1998129
```

And since `as.integer(1.1998129)` is equal to 1 you get the first row.

Now if you intended to do a join instead, you have to use the syntax `DT[J(...)]` or `DT[.(...)]`, and that will work as expected, provided you use the correct number (as a convenience, you're not required to use the `J` when dealing with e.g. character columns, because there is no default meaning for what `DT["a"]` would mean):

```
DT[J(v[5])]
#   x        v
#1: b 1.199813
```

Note that `DT[J(1.1998129)]` will not work, because:

```
DT$v[5] == 1.1998129
#[1] FALSE
```

You could print out a lot of digits, and that would work:

```
options(digits = 22)
DT$v[5]
#[1] 1.199812896606383683107

DT$v[5] == 1.199812896606383683107
#[1] TRUE

DT[J(1.199812896606383683107)]
#   x                v
#1: b 1.199812896606383683107
```

but there is an additional subtlety here, worth noting, in that R and `data.table` have different precisions for when floating point numbers are equal:

```
DT$v[5] == 1.19981289660638
#[1] FALSE
DT[J(1.19981289660638)]
#   x                       v
#1: b 1.199812896606379908349
```

Long story short - be careful when joining floating point numbers.

Comment: Is this `1.9.3`? If so how about precision after doing `setNumericRounding(0L)`?

Comment: @Arun yes, 1.9.3. After setting precision like you suggest, the two match up.